# Is there any way to simulate safari on the iphone 3 without access to the actual phone?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, ios3.0

I'm having the rather frustrating problem of a website problem on iphone 3 that doesn't appear on iphone 4.  I can't get my hands on an actual device.  I'm running windows.  Is there any way of simulating safari on iphone 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only way to emulate the iOS browser is with the iOS Simulator which is part of the iOS SDK, however this requires a Mac to run.

Comment: Mobile Safari in the current SDK Simulator will not simulate all the issues with the iPhone 3G Safari, especially one running iPhone OS 3.x.  The OP needs to find an actual iPhone 3G running the OS version of interest to beg, borrow, or steal.